# jQuery pagination not working on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I am building a page on Wordpress that has a DIV and inside that DIV there are many DIVs that share the same class, which I would like to paginate. I found a nice jQuery plugin that works fine on another page (not Wordpress). On the WP page, it initially shows the number of DIVs I set for pagination, but when clicking on NEXT/PAGE/PAGE NUMBER it shows nothing.

Works here (not Wordpress):

http://roshtof.co.il/second_hand.php

Doesn't work here:

http://roshtof.co.il/wp-rosh/%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9D/

Comment: You have an error in your javascript somewhere along the lines 327,328 on your page where lefttip is being started. Its using $ for jQuery but not inside a dom ready function. Put it in there and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin is working fine thats why it has brought up 16 items into 4 pages and does all initial work for you. There is an error on line 327 , 328

```
<script>
  $("#leftTip").load('http://roshtof.co.il/wp-rosh/%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9D/ #tips-for-drummers:first-child');
 </script>
```

You need to put this code inside dom ready event and it would work. Nothing to do with wordpress. All wordpress does is throw out html and js for you so once you have this issue fixed then it would be all fine.

Because of the js error the scripts on paging click are not working. Other stuff might be broken as well due to js error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not it. I fixed the JS error related to the line your wrote above - it was because of the '$'. Changed it to 'jQuery' and now it works. But that **didn't fix** the pagination clicks issue.

Comment: ok now i can see your pagination plugin is putting display:none and display:block on elements. On click its putting first 4 to display:none but its not putting display:block on next 4.

Comment: Yeah, it's strange... Do you know why this happens and how to fix it?